# create a new page from a custom post type similar to an authors page

Tags: custom-post-types, functions, author-template

I am looking for some direction here as I am unsure where to start. I have a CPT called 'videos' and one of my inputs is a 'artist_bio' text box that creates a box with a biography in it on my page.

```
<div class="bio">
    <?php the_field('artist_bio'); ?>
</div><!--bio-->
```

My client is asking if that biography can be an excerpt of what is entered with a read more link that takes you to a new page where more information beyond the biography lives. I'm unsure of how to get started, I have a authors link on the page that takes you to an authors page using author.php where more information on the author lives. This is how I get the authors link:

```
<?php the_author_posts_link(); ?>
```

I would like to mimic that set up but I'm not sure how?

Comment: You'd want to create a custom post type, or taxonomy, for `artist`. `artist` could contain an excerpt, and whatever else. In `video`, on the admin side, you'd create a relation to a post in `artist`. When viewing a `video` on the front end, you'd call the relation, get `artist where related to current video` and show the `artist` excerpt, with a link to the `artist`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I am using the Advanced Custom Fields plugin and they have a relationship field option so I was able to use that to get this to work. Much appreciated for your help in steering me in the correct direction.